# Execute a function for a column value every time a record is created in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running code that creates a record on a table in SQL Server 2014. The record is coming from my PHP backend that has an insert statement with new values. The table contains a 'reference_number' column that is supposed to be a concatenation of the first two letters of the 'type' column and an incrementing 7 digit number.

Now I could have done this easily playing with the column properties if it was just an incrementing integer value. So is there a way in SQL Server 2014 using functions or stored procedures (etc...) to give the column a generated value every time a new record is created?

For example I can use the built-in `getDate()` function every time I need to fill a datetime valued column. So can I write a function similar that accepts a parameter as the column value I am providing in the insert statement for the 'type' column and let the code do the rest? How?

Notes:

1. I am new to SQL server, although I know and have a background on the basics of databases in general.
2. Writing the code in PHP isn't a choice as its a specifically expected requirement I have to achieve.
3. Would love to hear new approaches/examples or recommendations on how to solve this.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an Identity column

```
    alter table myTable add column Sequencenumber
      int identity (1000000, 1) not null
                      ^     ^
 Start at this value  |     |
                            | //increment by this every time
```

Your reference number can then be a `computed column` using the `Identity` column and your `Type` column.

for example

```
alter table myTable add
Reference_number as
left(type,2) + cast(Sequencenumber as varchar(10))
```

See the documentation here [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property), and computed columns here [computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table)

Comment: Hey thanks but how can I concatenate the first two letters of the type column which vary with every record to the id number?

Comment: I just read your comments at the bottom. If there is no better ways then I will use your solution.  thanks.

Comment: Added example you could implement as a computed column.

Comment: Presumably the OP wants a zero-filled 7-digit number. Your `cast` won't provide the leading zeroes. Yes, you seeded the identity column with a large value, but not that large.

Comment: I read it as the table already had this number, so presumably, again, assumed this was taken care of. The OP can of course add more detail to the question and, if how to append a number with leading zeros is its own question, can ask that also. (maybe I missed a digit off on the seed, there is no detail in the question regarding what the format of a 7 digit number should be, but all 7 digit "numbers" start with a 1 and go from there :)

Comment: Don't worry, you are a life saver. The OP is already happy and satisfied with your answer @sTTu. Thank you!  :)

Comment: That's good to hear. Feel free to upvote it ;-)

Comment: If only I could. :( 
Can anybody who has the privilege help me out upvote this answer or mark as right?